# Prove that every matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a product of at most 4 elementary matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-groups

Prove that every matrix in $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is a product of at most 4 elementary matrices.

$GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ = set of invertible matrices of order 2×2.

How should i approach to prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that every elementary matrix operation can be achieved by multiplying the matrix with a suitable elementary matrix, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-switching_transformations). Now how many elementary matrix operations you need to perform to bring a matrix from $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ to an elementary matrix?